# error of adding a new column to dask cudf data frame from a 2-d numpy.darray

Tags: numpy, dask, numpy-ndarray, dask-dataframe, cudf

I would like to assign a new column to a dask cudf data frame from Jupyter notebook.

The new column is a 2-dimension numpy.ndarray.

My code:

```
import cudf
import dask_cudf
import numpy as np
from random import random

df = cudf.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": list(range(5)),
        "b": list(reversed(range(5))),
        "c": list(range(5)),
    }
)

ddf = dask_cudf.from_cudf(df, npartitions=2)
   

a = [[random()]*10 for _ in range(5)]    
nd_a = np.array(a)

   array([[0.05653035, 0.05653035, 0.05653035, 0.05653035, 0.05653035,
    0.05653035, 0.05653035, 0.05653035, 0.05653035, 0.05653035],
   [0.8034985 , 0.8034985 , 0.8034985 , 0.8034985 , 0.8034985 ,
    0.8034985 , 0.8034985 , 0.8034985 , 0.8034985 , 0.8034985 ],
   [0.68498022, 0.68498022, 0.68498022, 0.68498022, 0.68498022,
    0.68498022, 0.68498022, 0.68498022, 0.68498022, 0.68498022],
   [0.37803534, 0.37803534, 0.37803534, 0.37803534, 0.37803534,
    0.37803534, 0.37803534, 0.37803534, 0.37803534, 0.37803534],
   [0.2141872 , 0.2141872 , 0.2141872 , 0.2141872 , 0.2141872 ,
    0.2141872 , 0.2141872 , 0.2141872 , 0.2141872 , 0.2141872 ]])

type(nd_a), nd_a.shape
(numpy.ndarray, (5, 10))


type(ddf)
dask_cudf.core.DataFrame


ddf.assign(new_val_column=nd_a)

TypeError: Column assignment doesn't support type numpy.ndarray


import dask.dataframe as dd
ddf.assign(new_val_column=dd.from_array(nd_a))

TypeError: Column assignment does not support type dask.dataframe.core.DataFrame
```

I have tried to transform the 2-d array to "dask.array.from_array", "pd.Series", "dask.dataframe.from_array". But they do not work.

Please let me know if I missed out anything ?

========== **update** ==============

based on [Assign list as Dask-Dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68796634/assign-list-as-dask-dataframe-column), I tried:

```
import cudf
import dask_cudf
import numpy as np
from random import random
import dask.array as da

df = cudf.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": list(range(5)),
        "b": list(reversed(range(5))),
        "c": list(range(5)),
    }
)

ddf = dask_cudf.from_cudf(df, npartitions=2)
print(type(ddf), ddf.shape, ddf.npartitions)
# <class 'dask_cudf.core.DataFrame'> (Delayed('int-xxxx'), 3) 2

a = [[random()]*10 for _ in range(5)]    
nd_a = np.array(a)

print(type(nd_a), nd_a.shape)
# (numpy.ndarray, (5, 10))

chunks = ddf.map_partitions(lambda x: len(x)).compute().to_numpy()

my_array = da.from_array(nd_a, chunks=tuple(chunks))
# print(type(my_array), my_array.shape)
# (dask.array.core.Array (5, 10))

print(my_array.npartitions)
# 10

ddf.assign(new_val_column=my_array) # ValueError: Array assignment only supports 1-D arrays
```

How to assign a 2-d array to a dask_cudf DF ?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but a numpy suggestion: you can get a 2D numpy array of random numbers by doing `np.random.rand(5,10)` (using the legacy method). Although, you seem to have each row being the same value, which I am not sure was intended or not.

Comment: Now, to address your question, it appears the `cudf` is essentially a pandas `DataFrame`. You're trying to assign the entire numpy array to a single new column. Do you mean to have 10 new columns from the 10 columns of the numpy array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DASK: Typerrror: Column assignment doesn't support type numpy.ndarray whereas Pandas works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58254236/dask-typerrror-column-assignment-doesnt-support-type-numpy-ndarray-whereas-pa)

Comment: @jared, I added some updates.